# How to select all tags for a post with a given tag in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have three tables: posts, tags, and posts_tags. Posts store all the posts in my blog, tags stores all the different tags, and posts_tags stores the relationship between the two. For example, if the post with the id 2 is tagged with a tag with the id 3, posts_tags would store this relationship.

I want to construct a query where I can get all the posts tagged with a given id, and the other tags associated with those posts. For example, I want to be able to find all the posts tagged with 'programming' and all other tags associated with that post in one query.

Currently, I am using two queries: one to find the posts tagged with a given tag, and one to find all tags for those posts.

Is there any way to combine these queries into just one query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will return all posts that have the tag :search_tag and a second column listing, in a comma-delimited string, all *other* tags (not including the one you searched for) that apply to that post.  If the post has *only* the tag you request, it will appear in the list but the "additional_tags" column will be NULL).

```
 SELECT posts.id, GROUP_CONCAT(post_tags.tag) AS additional_tags
   FROM posts LEFT OUTER JOIN post_tags ON posts.id = post_tags.post_id
   WHERE posts.id IN (SELECT post_id FROM post_tags WHERE tag = :search_tag)
   AND post_tags.tag <> :search_tag
   GROUP BY posts.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your "programming" id is 1 and u want to get all posts with tag id 1

```
Select * from posts where tag_id in (select id from tag where id=1)
```

Comment: This answers only the first part of the question, and tabdulla already has a query that does that.  The trick is to answer both parts in a single query.